# Consume a START message from Kafka topic, look for an END message with same UID; log error if END message not read in 24 hours

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Need to write a Kafka app in Java that reads a JSON message like:

```
{"UID": "1234-5678", "type": "START"}
```

after this message is read there is an SLA of 24Hrs for an END message for to be consumed from the same topic

```
{"UID": "1234-5678", "type": "END"}
```

if this type:END message is not found, it should log an error to the console.

Comment: Can you post the code of whatever you've tried?

Comment: You're not really asking a question. What is it that you're having problems with? Is there an error? Have you tried something that is not working?

Comment: 1) Read data with Consumer 2) parse message 3) see start message 4) Try starting a `TimerTask` on separate thread 5) data is still being read, so wait for end message 6) if seen, stop the timer

Comment: What I am actually looking for is what to do next when I have consumed the message from the topic. Is there a way to hold message into some kind of in memory state store or should I dump my events into a database and run a scheduler to poll age of events in the DB ?

Comment: What's wrong with `ArrayList` or `HashMap`? Nothing says you have to process data immediately with the poll loop